# Should I seal my acrylic caulk?

Tags: bathtub, caulk, acrylic

I just used Speed Demon acrylic caulk around my bathtub--between the tub and the tiled wall. It does NOT have silicone in it. So is it ok as is, or for better waterproofing should I buy some kind of silicone sealer and apply it on top of the caulk? Would appreciate some input on this. Thanks.

Comment: Instructions should say if it needs sealing or not.

Comment: No one caulks caulk. :)

Answer (score 1):

UM, the stuff I use and all acrylic caulking I have ever seen or used is a sealant.

So I would not use an additional substance unless it is just some excess from sealing the grout but I seal my grout prior to adding caulk.